# How to solve unexpected antd datepicker behavior

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I need to disable select past datetime in Ant Datepicker.
Now, if u select time first u can select today (include past datetime). But if u select day first u can't select past time.
[Video demo [screencastify]](https://watch.screencastify.com/v/ggubtlc0kaiXNtyaiSFL)

```
<DatePicker
  disabledDate={getDisabledDate}
  disabledTime={getDisabledTimes}
  format="Do MMMM yyyy в HH:mm"
  onChange={(moment) => debouncedSetStartDate.run(moment ? moment.toDate() : null)}
  placeholder="Выберите дату и время"
  showNow={false}
  showTime
/>

const getDisabledDate = (date: Moment): boolean => {
  const current = moment().format(dateFormat.dateWithoutTime);
  return date.isSameOrBefore(current);
};

const getDisabledMinutes = (hour: number, currentHour: number, currentMinute: number) => {
  const result: number[] = [];
  if (hour === currentHour) {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentMinute + NEW_TOURNAMENT_START_DELAY_MINUTES; i += 1) {
      result.push(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
};

const getDisabledTimes = (date: null | Moment): DisabledTimes => {
  if (date === null) {
    return {};
  }

  const selected = moment(date.format(dateFormat.dateWithoutTime));
  const current = moment();
  const currentHour = current.hours();
  const currentMinute = current.minutes();
  const isToday = selected.isSame(current.format(dateFormat.dateWithoutTime));
  const hoursToDisable: number[] = [];

  if (isToday) {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentHour; i += 1) {
      hoursToDisable.push(i);
    }
  }

  return {
    disabledHours: () => hoursToDisable,
    disabledMinutes: (hour: number) => (isToday ? getDisabledMinutes(hour, currentHour, currentMinute) : []),
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, the problem in `getDisabledTimes` function, in `if (date === null)` check. By default, the `date`  argument is null on the first open and you can see all hours and minutes values.

I guess you should return some object from this check. For example:

```
const getDisabledTimes = (date: null | Moment): DisabledTimes => {
  if (date === null) {
    // you logic here
    return {
      disabledHours: () => range(0, 24).slice(0, moment().hour()),
      disabledMinutes: () => range(0, 60).slice(0, moment().minutes()),
    };
  }
  // else code
 }
```

Comment: unfortunately, date isn't equal null when u select time before date